# How to build event-sourcing read-models with orleans?

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing, orleans

I'm planning on using Orleans with event-sourcing. I'm going to create journalled grains. How do I consume events that many different types and instances of journalled grains emit to build read models?

What are the different pull\push based options?

If there aren't any, is it because cross-aggregate read-models is a bad idea?

Comment: I haven't used Orleans but this is wrong in any CQRS framework: `cross-aggregate read-models is a bad idea`

Comment: I've never been of the impression that a cross aggregate read model was bad. Eventually you will need to have data combined from separate aggregates and perhaps even separate bounded context for something like a display on a page. Either you can do that as a read model build directly from events or you can piece it together later with something like GraphQL.